# how to write integer and read as mush as size of integer in python

Tags: python

in Python, how can i write integer to pipe and read as mush as size of integer.

for example like below

the code below has some errors i know but it is to let you make sense what i want

```
# variable r and w is pipe descriptor for read and write respectively in thread1 and 2

# thread1
a = 10
w.write(a)     # i know it has an error occur as it requires string as the argument
```

.

```
# thread2
a = r.read(sys.getsizeof(1))   #read data as much as size of integer
if a == 1:
  #do something
elif a == 10:
  #do something
```

Comment: For the first block, try converting the integer into a string with str() before writing it. For the second block, did you import the sys module?

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` returns the size of Python's integer object not integer type.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module:

```
>>> import struct
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> c = StringIO()
>>> c.write(struct.pack('I', 100))
>>> c.seek(0)
>>> struct.unpack('I', c.read(4))
(100,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided that in this scenario the pipe is only way to move data between your threads, I would write a termination character after the integer, then simply watch for it in the second thread.

```
#thread 1
a = 10
w.write(str(a))
w.write('#')

#-----------

#thread 2
a = ""
b = r.read(1)
while(b != '#'):
    a = a + b
    b = r.read(1)

if int(a) == 1:
    #do something
```